# Non-overlaping fixed-width ranges with most occurrences

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I have encountered a following problem:

Given the list of $k$ values from range $[v_{min}; v_{max}]$, find $m$ non-overlaping ranges of length $l$, such that maximises the number of values from the original range that would fit into those new ranges.

For example:
Given a list `[2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32, 33, 40, 60, 61]`, if I wanted to find $m = 2$ ranges of length $l = 3$, the best solution would be choosing the ranges $[2; 5]$ and $[30; 33]$, for the total of eight common values—`[2, 3, 4, 5, 30, 31, 32, 33]`.

Mind you, in general case, there is *no* assumption that the values are integers.

Is that a known problem? What should I look for?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: (Be sure to either *find out* or *define* ranges to be *half-open* or *closed*.)

Answer (score -1):

I didn't encounter that question, but what I would do is use Counting sort(Because we have the range of values) and then I would loop over the sorted array and choose those m parts, I didn't quite understood the part - " find m non-overlaping ranges of length l, such that maximises the number of values from the original range that would fit into those new ranges."
but, in general, this costs you a linear time and choosing ranges will also cost you linear time, so in general: $O(n)$